# Find image of function $R \times R \to R \times R$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I have problem with understanding how to image where $$f(x,y)=<x+3, y-5>$$ where we want to find image of set $A= \{ <x,y> \in R\times R:y=x^2  \}$

from definition I want to find all $f(x,y) =<x+3, y-5>$ such that $ y=x^2$

I don't know what do to next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of a set is defined:

$$ f(A) = \{f((x,y)), (x,y) \in A\} $$

So what you are looking for is

$$ f(A) = \{(x+3,y-5), y=x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{(x+3, x^2 -5), x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{(t,(t-3)^2 - 5), t\in \mathbb{R}\} $$

So the wanted set is just a graph of a function $f(t) = (t-3)^2 - 5 $